# Simple Integer Optimization Problem: docplex CP model works but equivalent PuLP+CBC model is infeasible?

Tags: python, integer-programming, constraint-programming, docplex, pulp

I have an integer optimization problem with one constraint per decision variable and no objective function. It can be coded and solved using `docplex`, however I am struggling to implement an equivalent model in `PuLP`.

## Problem

Given a series with indices `0...n`, find integer values of the series such that the value for each index `i` corresponds to the number of occurrences of `i` in the series.

For example, a solution for `n = 4` is:

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 |

For index `i=0`, the value is `2`, which corresponds to the series "2, 1, 2, 0, 0" containing two occurrences of the value `0`. Index `i=1` has a value of `1`, corresponding to the single occurrence of `1` in the series. And so on.

## Docplex implementation works!

```
from docplex.cp.model import CpoModel

# Data
n = 5
NUMBERS = range(n)

# Model instance
mdl = CpoModel(name='find series')

# Decision variables
s = mdl.integer_var_list(n, 0, n-1, "series")

# Constraint: Value should equal the # of occurrences of the index in the series

for i in NUMBERS:
    mdl.add(sum(s[j] == i for j in NUMBERS) == s[i])

# Solve
msol = mdl.solve()
```

## PuLP attempts do NOT work!

Not sure if it matters, but I'm using the default CBC `PuLP` solver in both attempts below.

### Attempt 1

In this attempt, the `if` statement of the constraint seems to always evaluate to `True`, such that the constraints become `X[i] = 5`, which is infeasible since the maximum value of the decision variables is `n = 4`.

```
from pulp import *

# Data
n = 4
NUMBERS = range(n+1)

# Model instance
model = LpProblem("FindSeries")

# Decision variables
X = LpVariable.dicts('X', NUMBERS, lowBound=0, upBound=n, cat=LpInteger)

# Constraint: Value should equal the # of occurrences of the index in the series
for i in NUMBERS:
    model += lpSum([1 for j in NUMBERS if X[j]==i]) - X[i] == 0

# Solve
model.solve()
```

The constraints look like:

```
_C1: - X_0  = -5
_C2: - X_1  = -5
_C3: - X_2  = -5
_C4: - X_3  = -5
_C5: - X_4  = -5
```

### Attempt 2

When the above failed, I tried implementing the constraint another way, more similar to the `docplex` code.

```
# Constraint: Value should equal the # of occurrences of the index in the series
for i in NUMBERS:
    model += lpSum([X[j]==i for j in NUMBERS]) == X[i]
```

This time, I'm totally confused about what is going on. The model constraints look like this:

```
_C1: 0 X_0 + X_1 + X_2 + X_3 + X_4 = 0
_C2: X_0 + 0 X_1 + X_2 + X_3 + X_4 = 5
_C3: X_0 + X_1 + 0 X_2 + X_3 + X_4 = 10
_C4: X_0 + X_1 + X_2 + 0 X_3 + X_4 = 15
_C5: X_0 + X_1 + X_2 + X_3 + 0 X_4 = 20
```

## Questions

- Is it possible to solve this using `PuLP` + default CBC solver?

  - If not, why not?
  - If so,

    - How can I code the model correctly in `PuLP`?
    - Why did my `PuLP` attempts fail as they did?

Comment: I am not sure, but I think this `sum(s[j] == i for j in NUMBERS)` is the problem. It seems you are summing over boolean-expressions where you count one up, if `s[j]=i`. This seems to be specific syntax for CPLEX. At least it looks very much like the syntax used in OPL - see e.g. under "Logical constraints for counting"  at [the cplex documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/icos/12.8.0.0?topic=constraints-logical-cplex)

Answer (score 3):

A simple equivalent MIP model can be built as follows.

Introduce a binary variable $y_{i,j}\in\{0,1\}$ such that
$y_{i,j}=1\Leftrightarrow x_i=j$. The problem can now be formulated as a straight MIP model (just add a dummy objective):

$$
\begin{aligned}
   &x_i = \sum_j j\cdot y_{i,j}&& \forall i && \text{extract value}\\
   &\sum_j y_{i,j} = 1 && \forall i && \text{exactly one value in each row of $y$}\\
   &x_i = \sum_j y_{j,i} && \forall i && \text{count occurrences}\\
   &y_{i,j} \in \{0,1\}
\end{aligned}
$$

If you want, you can substitute out $x_i$ and recover those values during reporting.

Comment: Thanks, I am already aware that this is an alternative problem formulation. But my goal is to implement the same problem formulation in `PuLP` which I know works in `docplex` (or if that is not possible, to understand why).

Comment: Sorry, I must have missed that in your question. Of course, this is because CP$\ne$ MIP.

Comment: Do I understand your comment to mean that it is actually impossible for CBC/`PuLP` to solve the problem as formulated? If so, that partially answers my question, although I still don't understand what it the fundamental difference in the way the problem is defined, or how `PuLP` is interpreting the problem.

Comment: You solved it in docplex using constraint programming (CP). PuLP does not support CP (and CBC is not a CP solver). So all kinds of CP constraints cannot be used directly.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are confusing the variables of your problem ($x_i$) with the parameters (the number of occurrences $s_i$). The way I understand your problem is as follows:

The mathematical expression of your constraint is
$$
\sum_{j}x_j = s_i \quad \mbox{for all }i
$$
where $s_i$ denotes the number of occurrences of value $i$ in the series.

With PuLP:

```
for i in s:
   model += lpSum(x[j] for j in x) == s[i]
```

---

**EDIT**

I misunderstood the question and am editing according the comments below. So the constraint is
$$
\sum_{j}|\{j : x_j=i\}| = x_i \quad \mbox{for all }i
$$

This is not a linear constraint and thus cannot be implemented as is in PuLp. I suggest to use Erwin's MIP below, which can be solved with PuLp.

Comment: The values of $s_i$ are not given.  The desired constraint is instead $$\sum_j |\{j: x_j = i\}| = x_i,$$ where $|.|$ denotes cardinality.

Comment: @RobPratt is correct. Also please see the `docplex` solution in my question, which works as desired, and has a very similar syntax to my second attempt at a `PuLP` solution. That may help clarify the intent.